# OpenGraph properties in an MVC5 shared view

Tags: model-view-controller, facebook-opengraph

I'm wanting to put my OpenGraph properties into a shared view to be used across multiple pages however [Facebooks sharing debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) is giving me back errors despite following the [open graph](http://ogp.me/) documentation.

### The Code

```
<head>
    <meta property="og:image" content="www.myimage.co.uk/images/image.png"/>
    <meta property="og:title" content="@ViewBag.Title">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="...">
    <meta property="og:url" content="www.myimage.co.uk/">
    <meta property="og:description" content="...">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
</head>
```

## Facebook debugger

When I submit my url into the debugger and press debug, and even scrape again to make sure it's giving me back this error:

Inferred Property
The 'og:image' property should be explicitly provided, even if a value can be inferred from other tags.

I've also inspected my webpage in the browser and the code is exactly as stated above. Is there something obvious that I'm missing?

## Edit:

Using the 'scraped url' option on Facebook's debugger, it shows that the meta tag's aren't being picked up by Facebook's scraper - is there a way of ensuring that this data is picked up by a scraper?